# Ubuntu 19,10 pactl connection refused

Tags: 19.10

after running

```
> sudo pactl set-sink-volume 0 150%
```

I faced error

> Connection failure: Connection refused pa_context_connect() failed:
>   Connection refused

Answer (score 1):

Normally pilseaudio runs as normal user.

```
ps -ef | grep pulse
```

No need for using sudo.

Comment: I tried without sudo and got `Failure: Module initialization failed` when loading modules like `pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover`